# Update never completes

Tags: 16.04, updates

I would say I'm between noob and mediocre with Ubuntu. I'm currently running 16.04 and I've had a problem for about a week now where updating never ends. Eventually, I reboot and cannot do any installs/updates until this is resolved.

Both `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get install -f` result in the same thing that happened in the normal update window. More specifically the last line:

```
gord0@gord0-P65-P67SG:/var/lib/dpkg/updates$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  python-compizconfig
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
42 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (55.0.2883.75-1) ...
Setting up imagemagick-common (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.2) ...
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz [27.2 MB]
Fetched 27.2 MB in 11s (2,462 kB/s)                                            
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Installing from local file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz
Flash Plugin installed.
Setting up libisc-export160 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libdns-export162 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up bind9-host (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up firefox (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up firefox-locale-en (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libgs9-common (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up libgs9:amd64 (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up ghostscript (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up ghostscript-x (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up imagemagick-6.q16 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up imagemagick (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
```

it just stays at `run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic` forever :/

I just want this update installed and out of my life lol! Any help is greatly appreciated. :]

**Edit**: The results of `dkms status` are:

```
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.20, 4.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Edit**: The results of `ls -al /usr/src` are:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Nov 30 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Nov 21 15:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 21 15:04 bbswitch-0.8
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jul 19 17:47 linux-headers-4.4.0-31
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jul 19 17:47 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov 21 14:37 linux-headers-4.4.0-47
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Nov 21 14:37 linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov 30 11:22 linux-headers-4.4.0-51
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Nov 30 11:22 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Nov 21 15:29 nvidia-375-375.20
```

**Edit**: The output for `ls /boot` is:

```
abi-4.4.0-31-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.4.0-47-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.4.0-51-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.4.0-31-generic      System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
config-4.4.0-47-generic      System.map-4.4.0-47-generic
config-4.4.0-51-generic      System.map-4.4.0-51-generic
efi                          vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
```

**Edit**: The output from `sudo make` in `/usr/src/nvidia375-375.20` :

```
make "CC=cc"  KBUILD_VERBOSE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/build M=/usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20 ARCH=x86_64 NV_KERNEL_SOURCES=/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/build NV_KERNEL_OUTPUT=/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/build NV_KERNEL_MODULES="nvidia nvidia-uvm nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm" INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/video modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic'
 CONFTEST: INIT_WORK
 CONFTEST: remap_pfn_range
 CONFTEST: follow_pfn
 CONFTEST: vmap
 CONFTEST: set_pages_uc
 CONFTEST: set_memory_uc
 CONFTEST: set_memory_array_uc
 CONFTEST: change_page_attr
 CONFTEST: pci_get_class
 CONFTEST: pci_choose_state
 CONFTEST: vm_insert_page
 CONFTEST: acpi_device_id
 CONFTEST: acquire_console_sem
 CONFTEST: console_lock
 CONFTEST: kmem_cache_create
 CONFTEST: on_each_cpu
 CONFTEST: smp_call_function
 CONFTEST: acpi_evaluate_integer
 CONFTEST: ioremap_cache
 CONFTEST: ioremap_wc
 CONFTEST: acpi_walk_namespace
 CONFTEST: pci_domain_nr
 CONFTEST: pci_dma_mapping_error
 CONFTEST: sg_alloc_table
 CONFTEST: sg_init_table
 CONFTEST: pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot
 CONFTEST: get_num_physpages
 CONFTEST: efi_enabled
 CONFTEST: proc_create_data
 CONFTEST: pde_data
 CONFTEST: proc_remove
 CONFTEST: pm_vt_switch_required
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_set_busid
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_res_obj
 CONFTEST: xen_ioemu_inject_msi
 CONFTEST: phys_to_dma
 CONFTEST: get_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: write_cr4
 CONFTEST: of_parse_phandle
 CONFTEST: for_each_online_node
 CONFTEST: node_end_pfn
 CONFTEST: pci_bus_address
 CONFTEST: pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: pci_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: request_threaded_irq
 CONFTEST: remap_page_range
 CONFTEST: address_space_init_once
 CONFTEST: kbasename
 CONFTEST: fatal_signal_pending
 CONFTEST: list_cut_position
 CONFTEST: vzalloc
 CONFTEST: wait_on_bit_lock_argument_count
 CONFTEST: bitmap_clear
 CONFTEST: usleep_range
 CONFTEST: radix_tree_empty
 CONFTEST: drm_dev_unref
 CONFTEST: drm_reinit_primary_mode_group
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_set_mode_for_crtc
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_clean_old_fb
 CONFTEST: get_user_pages_remote
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_lookup
 CONFTEST: i2c_adapter
 CONFTEST: pm_message_t
 CONFTEST: irq_handler_t
 CONFTEST: acpi_device_ops
 CONFTEST: acpi_op_remove
 CONFTEST: outer_flush_all
 CONFTEST: proc_dir_entry
 CONFTEST: scatterlist
 CONFTEST: sg_table
 CONFTEST: file_operations
 CONFTEST: vm_operations_struct
 CONFTEST: atomic_long_type
 CONFTEST: pci_save_state
 CONFTEST: file_inode
 CONFTEST: task_struct
 CONFTEST: kuid_t
 CONFTEST: dma_ops
 CONFTEST: dma_map_ops
 CONFTEST: noncoherent_swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: fault_flags
 CONFTEST: atomic64_type
 CONFTEST: address_space
 CONFTEST: backing_dev_info
 CONFTEST: kernel_write
 CONFTEST: strnstr
 CONFTEST: iterate_dir
 CONFTEST: kstrtoull
 CONFTEST: mm_context_t
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_present
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_bus_type
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_irq
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_name
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_legacy_dev_list
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_connectors_changed
 CONFTEST: drm_init_functions_have_name_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_connector_list_update_has_merge_type_bits_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct_has_const_mode_cmd_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_master_drop_has_from_release_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_config_funcs_has_atomic_state_alloc
 CONFTEST: dom0_kernel_present
 CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_kvm_build
 CONFTEST: drm_available
 CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_build
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_available
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_modeset_nonblocking_commit_available
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-frontend.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-instance.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-acpi.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-chrdev.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-cray.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-dma.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-gvi.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-i2c.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-mempool.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-mmap.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-p2p.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-pat.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-procfs.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-usermap.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-vm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-vtophys.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-interface.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-mlock.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-pci.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-registry.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-usermap.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-pci-table.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-kthread-q-selftest.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/ebridge_linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/ibmnpu_linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nvlink_linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nvlink_pci.o
  SYMLINK /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_utils.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_common.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_migration.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_migration_stubs.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_migration_kepler.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_migration_maxwell.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_migration_pascal.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_channel_mgmt.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/nvstatus.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/nv-kthread-q.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/nv-kthread-q-selftest.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_common_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_channel_directed_tests.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_channel_basic_sanity_tests.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_kernel_events.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_kernel_counters.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_debug_session.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_gpu_ops_tests.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_lite.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_page_cache.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_lite_api.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_lite_prefetch.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_lite_region_tracking.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu_mgmt_pascal.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu_mgmt.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu_mgmt_stubs.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_full_fault_buffer.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm_full_fault_buffer_pascal.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/mmu_fmt.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/gmmu_fmt.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tools.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_global.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_procfs.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_space.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_semaphore.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mem.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_rm_mem.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_channel.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_lock.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_hal.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_tree.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_allocator.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_range.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_group.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_page_fault.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_events.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_module.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mmu.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pte_batch.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tlb_batch.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_push.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pushbuffer.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_thread_context.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tracker.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_ce.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_host.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kepler_mmu.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_maxwell.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_maxwell_host.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_ce.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_host.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_mmu.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pascal_fault_buffer.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_policy.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_utils.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kvmalloc.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_gpu.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_migrate.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_map_external.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_user_channel.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_hmm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_heuristics.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_thrashing.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_prefetch.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_test_rng.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_tree_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_allocator_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_gpu_semaphore_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mem_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_rm_mem_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_page_tree_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_tracker_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_push_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_channel_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_ce_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_lock_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_utils_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_kvmalloc_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_pmm_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_events_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_perf_module_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_get_rm_ptes_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_fault_buffer_flush_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_mmu_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_peer_identity_mappings_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block_test.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_range_group_tree_test.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset/nvidia-modeset-linux.o
  SYMLINK /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-drv.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-utils.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-crtc.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-encoder.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-connector.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-gem.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fb.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-modeset.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-mmap.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-fence.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nvidia-drm-linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm/nv-pci-table.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm.o
ld -r -o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-interface.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-frontend.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-instance.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-acpi.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-chrdev.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-cray.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-dma.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-gvi.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-i2c.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-mempool.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-mmap.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-p2p.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-pat.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-procfs.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-usermap.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-vm.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-vtophys.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-interface.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-mlock.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-pci.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-registry.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/os-usermap.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-pci-table.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-kthread-q.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv-kthread-q-selftest.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/ebridge_linux.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/ibmnpu_linux.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nvlink_linux.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia/nvlink_pci.o
ld -r -o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-interface.o /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset/nvidia-modeset-linux.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 4 modules
  CC      /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-drm.ko
  CC      /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-modeset.ko
  CC      /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia-uvm.ko
  CC      /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20/nvidia.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic'
```

**Edit**: The output for `cat dkms.conf` in the above mentioned directory is:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="nvidia-375"
PACKAGE_VERSION="375.20"
CLEAN="make clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="nvidia"
DEST_MODULE_NAME[0]="nvidia_375"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/char/drm"
MAKE[0]="'make' -j$(nproc) NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=${kernelver} IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=$kernel_source_dir LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[1]="nvidia-modeset"
DEST_MODULE_NAME[1]="nvidia_375_modeset"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="/kernel/drivers/char/drm"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[2]="nvidia-drm"
DEST_MODULE_NAME[2]="nvidia_375_drm"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="/kernel/drivers/char/drm"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
#PATCH[0]="buildfix_kernel_4.9.patch"
#PATCH_MATCH[0]="^4.9"
#PATCH[0]="buildfix_kernel_4.8.patch"
#PATCH[0]="buildfix_kernel_4.6.patch"
#PATCH_MATCH[0]="^4.[6-7]"
#PATCH[0]="allow_sublevel_greater_than_5.patch"
#PATCH_MATCH[0]="^3.[8-9]"
#PATCH[1]="buildfix_kernel_3.10.patch"
#PATCH_MATCH[1]="^3.[10-11]"
#PATCH[0]="buildfix_kernel_3.18.patch"
#PATCH[1]="register-VT-switch-requirements.patch"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[3]="nvidia-uvm"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[3]="/kernel/drivers/char/drm"
DEST_MODULE_NAME[3]="nvidia_375_uvm"
#PATCH[1]="buildfix_kernel_4.7_amd64_only.patch"
```

Comment: In `terminal`, type `dkms status` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: @heynnema done :]

Comment: It may be that your nvidia driver is causing the problem. It's not getting built for the new kernel 4.4.0-51. I'd research that you have the correct/newest available nvidia driver. You'd have to install a new one on the current 4.4.0-47 kernel first. If that doesn't pan out, I'll give you some manual commands to try and move on. What's the output of `uname -r`? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema the output is: `4.4.0-47-generic`

Comment: That's what I thought the answer would be. Go and research the nvidia driver. Report back.

Comment: According to the nvidia site I have the latest stable driver (geforce 980m). Only way to get a newer one is to go beta.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to put together an answer that will hold my detail...

Comment: Give me the output of `ls -al /usr/src`. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Do you have the original nvidia-375 v375.20 installer close at hand? Also give me the output of `ls /boot`.

Comment: I added the output to my origial post above. I haven't tried what's in your answer yet. I can re-download the driver... but I'm fairly sure I used `apt-get install nvidia-375` . Would that have saved the installer somewhere or just straight up installed?

Comment: I don't see nvidia-375 in Synaptic. Maybe you added a nvidia repository to get the latest drivers? Or you downloaded from their web site? Remember to give me the output of `ls /boot`. Don't do my partial answer until I say so...

Comment: See if you find the `nvidia-375` installer at `ls /var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the output, and yes the .deb for the driver is in `/var/cache/apt/archives` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nvidia dkms driver build fails, so we'll manually try and help it along.

## step #1 (success)

We'll completely remove the nvidia dkms driver.

```
dkms status # will show nvidia on 4.4.0-47

sudo dkms remove nvidia-375/375.20 --all

dkms status # shouldn't see the nvidia at all
```

## step #2 (success)

We'll try and finish the update that failed before.

```
sudo apt-get update

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get install -f
```

Run Software Updater from the Unity dashboard.

If it didn't reboot during the previous 3 commands:

```
reboot
```

Report back.

## step #3 (failed at build, as we thought it might)

Now we'll add/build/install the nvidia dkms driver.

```
uname -r # only proceed if it shows 4.4.0-51

sudo dkms add nvidia-375/375.20

dkms status # nvidia should show as added on 4.4.0-51

sudo dkms build nvidia-375/375.20 -k 4.4.0-51-generic

dkms status # nvidia should show as built on 4.4.0-51

sudo dkms install nvidia-375/375.20 -k 4.4.0-51-generic

dkms status # nvidia should show as installed on 4.4.0-51

reboot
```

## step #4 (success)

```
sudo dkms remove nvidia-375/375.20 --all

cd /usr/src/nvidia-375-375.20 # go to the source code directory

sudo make clean # make sure it's a clean directory

sudo make # build the source without dkms, if it can
```

- copy/paste all output of `make` (edit it into your question)
- put `<pre>` at beginning of text, and `</pre>` at the end of the text

```
sudo make clean # clean it out again
```

Bottom line... the nvidia driver won't `dkms build` on kernel 4.4.0. Problem may be with the dkms.conf file. User needs to contact nvidia for support. Might also try nvidia reinstall from the .deb file located at `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: How long should I let step 1 go for? It's been going for quite a while now. A few lines of output and many lines of dots.

Comment: Shouldn't take more than 5 minutes. If it's longer, we found our problem. Let me update the steps...

Comment: Do the new steps #1 and #2. Report back. Bedtime here. I'll check back in the A.M.

Comment: steps 1 and 2 were completely successful, should I go ahead with 3 or have you come up with a better approach in your slumber?

Comment: If you haven't rebooted yet, do so, and show me `uname -r`. If it's 4.4.0-51 then go ahead with step #3. It may fail at the `build` phase again. I'll decide what to do if that happens later.

Comment: Yeah it does that infinite dot thing again during the `sudo dkms build nvidia-375/375.20 -k 4.4.0-51-generic` part of step 3

Comment: Do step #4. Report back.

Comment: Done and output edited into question. :]

Comment: Looks fine. Go back to the source code directory and `cat dkms.conf` and edit that into your question. We've identified the problem as the nvidia driver. I went to the nvidia website and read some of the extended notes on this driver. Kind of scary. I guess that what I've see here on AU is a big conversation regarding nividia vs nouveau drivers. Here's where my experience stops. You could try to reinstall the drivers using the deb file in /var/cache/apt/archives. You may have to run step #1 again if it screws up. Or you... continued in next comment...

Comment: Or you might have to run with the nouveau driver. I'd suggest researching it more yourself. Maybe start a new question about the nvidia driver problem. If I see anything with dkms.conf I'll let you know. Please do keep me posted. Begin new comments with `@heynnema` to make sure that I see them.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output. Hopefully you see something as nouveau is not an option for anyone who likes things not to look like garbage. I'm a game dev so nouveau would make both playing and making games ubearable to look at. Heck even watching youtube looks crap with nouveau.

Comment: That's quite a dkms.conf file! It contains a bunch of patch statements... for every kernel except 4.4.0. You need to contact nvidia and tell them that nvidia 375-375.20 won't dkms build on kernel 4.4.0. As I mentioned earlier, you might try and reinstall using the deb file. You know enough about the `dkms status` and `dkms remove` commands to tell if it installed correctly.

Comment: Yeah the initial issue is resolved and this thread contains the info to re-fix it if I re-break it. Thanks so much for your help! I'll comment again if I sort out the nvidia problem.

Comment: You're very welcome! Remember to begin new comments with `@heynnema` to make sure that I see them. I'll be interested to hear the final outcome.

Comment: @heyynnema I ended up borking things up so bad that I just reinstalled ubuntu. I then did the following and everything seems fine: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` which connects me to an update server solely for stable nvidia drivers. `sudo apt update` then revealed there was some things that needed updates. `sudo apt upgrade` installed them and then to my delight driver 375.20 was now listed in Additional Hardware. I switched to it and rebooted. Now everything works again. I can switch between onboard and discrete via the nvidia x server settings. cont in next reply...

Comment: ...If I encounter the update issue found in this thread, I should be able to remove it from dkms and then readd after the update is done.

Cheers again for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the update! No more borking... ok :-)